# Speed up Computation

Tags: r

I have this code; it's slow and I want it to be faster (i.e. write in in one line w/out the for loop)

```
n = 1000000
x = numeric(n)
for (i in 1:n) x[i] = rpois(1, 3) + rpois(1, 5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rpois` function is vectorised so this should work for you :

```
n = 1000000
x <- rpois(n, 3) + rpois(n, 5)
```